# Create a CD/DVD ISO Image in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cddvd

I'm searching for a library (or codebase) which will allow the creation of an ISO image from a CD/DVD with the .NET platform.

Does the .NET framework itself support the creation of ISO images?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DVD ISO from C# - .NET DiscUtils alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685894/dvd-iso-from-c-sharp-net-discutils-alternatives)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.Net itself cannot create or manipulate ISO images.

You can search Google for [ISO libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+iso+cd+image+C%23); I found [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/).

Comment: @SLaks: Thank you ! not sure why I didn't think of that, must be gettin old and forgetful. My google-fu isn't what it used to be.

Comment: Excellent recommendation - easy to use!

Comment: It is possible to use the IMAPI COM objects for this, and these should be easy to use from .NET.  Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8324075/223837.

Answer (score 3):

Or this one: http://isocs.codeplex.com/

Bad spelling, but also works with DVDs.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for ISO handling in general (reading AND writing) and I found this page: [.NET DiscUtils](http://discutils.codeplex.com/)

MIT License, only managed code and supports FAT, NTFS and virtual machine images. Might be worth a look if you want to read back your stuff.

Comment: Since Codplex has been shutdown, the latest DiscUtils (as of this writing) can be found at https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils

Comment: Can someone explain how I can add the DiscUtils to a project? I don't understand how to do that and the documentation isn't very clear. I am still learning C#.