# DVD ISO from C# - .NET DiscUtils alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, dvd, iso9660

What is the best way to make **.ISO files** based on a file folder structure from C#? Is there an open source library other than [DiscUtils](http://discutils.codeplex.com/)? Running into issues with **DiscUtils** and I'd like try another path. What are my options? I'd prefer open source but might also be willing to pay for a solution.

Comment: Considering using **DiscUtils** for a current project requirement...what exact issues were you having?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some more to try

- [C# [ISO] image creator](http://isocs.codeplex.com/) (*no support for audio CDs*)
- [IsoCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/)

Answer (score 5):

Windows actually comes with a native API for creating ISOs and much more: the [Image Mastering API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/imapi/portal). Once you grab the IMAPI2 Interop assembly from the Windows SDK or (probably easier) from [this CodeProject article about IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an), creating an ISO is only a few lines of code.

Unfortunately, you also need a few paragraphs to properly clean up the COM nonsense involved, but the end result is still pretty manageable:

```
MsftFileSystemImage iso = new MsftFileSystemImage();
iso.ChooseImageDefaultsForMediaType(IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE.IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_DISK);
iso.FileSystemsToCreate = FsiFileSystems.FsiFileSystemISO9660 | FsiFileSystems.FsiFileSystemJoliet;

iso.Root.AddTree(@"c:\path\goes\here\", false);

dynamic resultImage = iso.CreateResultImage();
dynamic imageStream = resultImage.ImageStream;
IStream newStream = null;

if (imageStream != null)
{
    STATSTG stat = null;
    imageStream.Stat(stat, 0x1);

    int res = SHCreateStreamOnFile(@"c:\path\to\your.iso", 0x1001, newStream);
    if (res == 0 && newStream != null)
    {
        IntPtr inBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(long)));
        IntPtr outBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(long)));
        try
        {
            imageStream.CopyTo(newStream, stat.cbSize, inBytes, outBytes);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(imageStream);
            newStream.Commit(0);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(newStream);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inBytes);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outBytes);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(resultImage);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(iso);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(imageStream);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(resultImage);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(iso);
        //TODO: Throw exception or do whatever to signal failure here
    }
}    
else
{
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(resultImage);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(iso);
    //TODO: Throw exception or do whatever to signal failure here
}
```

Details for the only bit of Win32/COM API glue used can be found on pinvoke.net: [SHCreateStreamOnFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.shcreatestreamonfile). IStream and STATSTG are in [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.aspx).

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to work as written; there are multiple issues with types and function parameters. The example should also show the appropriate `using` statements and P/Invoke declarations required.

Comment: Also, calling `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` is not required (and is in fact potentially bad). The runtime takes care of the references automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Primo Burner: http://www.primoburner.com/Downloads.aspx